# ImportError: cannot import name 'export_saved_model' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.saving.saved_model'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

While running yolo detection on webcam, I came across this error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'export_saved_model' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.saving.saved_model'
```

and its indicated on this line

```
from yolov3_tf2.models import YoloV3, YoloV3Tiny
```

I saw this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61833301/error-on-tensorflow-cannot-import-name-export-saved-model) but it is of no use for me.

I did tried this..

```
conda uninstall -y tensorflow
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip uninstall keras
```

and then

```
conda create -n tf tensorflow
conda activate tf
```

and still the error persists..

Here is the full traceback call..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Github/cloned repo/Object-Detection-API/load_weights.py", line 4, in <module>
    from yolov3_tf2.models import YoloV3, YoloV3Tiny
  File "d:\Github\cloned repo\Object-Detection-API\yolov3_tf2\models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras import Model
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\keras\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import activations
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\keras\activations\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.activations import deserialize
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import keras
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import activations
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\activations.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.generic_utils import deserialize_keras_object
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.multi_gpu_utils import multi_gpu_model
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\multi_gpu_utils.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training import Model
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 43, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.network import Network
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.saving import hdf5_format
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.saving.saved_model import export_saved_model
ImportError: cannot import name 'export_saved_model' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.saving.saved_model' (D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saved_model\__init__.py)
```

Help me solve this error..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I noticed this upon writing `import keras` I'm getting the same error so where can the problem be?